# Counting PivotTables from an Excel Workbook with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-2010, powershell-2.0

I have a problem with powershell and excel.

First of all my powershell version is 2 and excel version is 2010 x86.

My code is:

```
#Start Excel
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel") | Out-Null
    $ObjXls = New-Object "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass"
    $ObjXls.Visible = $False
    $ObjXls.ScreenUpdating = $False
    $ObjXls.DisplayAlerts = $False
#Open the template workbook
    [String] $Private:TemplateFilePath = "$($Params['TEMPLATE_PATH'])\$TemplateFileName" 
    WriteLog -Message "Template file: $TemplateFilePath"
    $WbXls = $ObjXls.Workbooks.open($TemplateFilePath) 
    $WbXls.RefreshAll()
#Counting Pivot Tables
    ForEach ($sheet in $WbXls.Worksheets)
    {
        if ($sheet.Name -ne "LiteDB") {
       [int]$count = $sheet.PivotTables.Count
       [string]$sheetname = $sheet.Name
       writelog ($sheetname + " --- " + $count)

      For ($i = 0; $i -le $sheet.PivotTables.Count; $i++)  {    
      if (-not $sheet.PivotTables($i).RefreshTable()) {throw "Unable to refresh PivotTable"}
      $sheet.PivotTables($i).RefreshTable()
      $sheet.PivotTables($i).PivotFields("Week").CurrentPage=$Currentweek
      }
     }
     }
```

To be clear the "Writelog" command is a library created by me to generate a logfile, it

works so don't worry about it.

The output is the name of the sheets and the count of the pivot tables... but:

```
NS --- 0,   SM --- 0,  QTY --- 0
```

On each sheet i have one pivot table, but what is wrong? why is not recognizing the pivots on the sheets?

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

PivotTables is a method of the worksheet object, not a property. So in C# (unlike in VBA), you should express the method call with parentheses.

```
[int]$count = $sheet.PivotTables.Count
```

should be

```
[int]$count = $sheet.PivotTables().Count
```